# Can calling mixpanel.track cause reattribution of conversions in Mixpanel funnels?

Tags: analytics, conversions, a-b-testing

I am currently using MixPanel to A/B test which of two different [landing page](http://www.candyjapan.com) images converts better. At the beginning of each hit to the page, I do

```
mixpanel.track('Main', {illustration_ab : '{{illustration_ab}}'});
```

Here illustration_ab contains the name of the image that was shown to the user. Then after gathering data, later on I can go look at the funnels and split by this variable to see which has higher conversion rate.

I just started wondering though, if someone converts but then comes back to the page later and gets assigned another illustration_ab, will that get the user's past conversion reattributed to fall under the different image?

[image]